# Visual Studio Code, how to switch from cmd.exe to node

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm using windows 7, And I couldn't run ng serve in my VS code terminal and on the normal terminal, I had to download Node terminal to run it, But I'm not able to get that Node Terminal in my VS CODE So that I can directly start ng-serve from VS Code itself.

Your help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: You need to have Angular CLI installed globally, and restart VS afterwards so that it's in the cmd path. Instructions are on the home page: https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Still it goes the same error sir